# IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled

Tags: c#, indexoutofrangeexception, unhandled

I'm getting an error `IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled` at the line `int euros = int.Parse(values[1])`.

My .csv file looks:

```
name,   1,  2
name1,  3,  4
name2,  5,  6
```

---

```
 public static void ReadData(out Turistai[] tourists, out int amount)
    {
        amount = 0;
        tourists = new Turistai[MaxTourists];
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Andrius\\Desktop\\Mokslams\\C#\\Pratybos\\P2\\P2.1\\turistai.csv"))
        {
            string line = null;
            while( (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
            {
                string[] values = line.Split(';');

                string name = values[0];
                int euros = int.Parse(values[1]);
                int cents = int.Parse(values[2]);
                Console.WriteLine(euros);
                //Turistai tourists = new Turistai(name, euros, cents);
                amount++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Andrius. I've cast a vote to to close your post. Please see the How to Ask page for info on the kinds of questions that are useful here. Posts that are basically code-dumps followed by an implicit or explicit "Please solve this for me" are frowned upon. You should use a debugger to step through the code instead.

Comment: as @ray said: use the debugger, set the cursor to `string[] values = line.split(';');`, hit F9 and go F5. Then you can step through it. move your cursor over `values` and view the content.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV input is *comma* separated while in the code you're splitting by *semicolons*. Change the `split()` parameter to `,`:

```
string[] values = line.Split(',');
```

You may also want to add input format check to ensure the `values` array contains at least three items and the numeric fields do actually contain integer values (`int.TryParse()` may help with this):

```
while( (line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
{
    string[] values = line.Split(',');
    if (values.Length < 3)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid input line: " + line);
        continue;
    }

    string name = values[0];
    int euros;
    if (!int.TryParse(values[1], out euros))
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid euros value in the line: " + line);
        continue;
    }
    int cents;
    if (!int.TryParse(values[2], out cents))
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("Invalid cents value in the line: " + line);
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(euros);
    //Turistai tourists = new Turistai(name, euros, cents);
    amount++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just accidentally put a wrong symbol, however the problem remains the same- i get the same error. EDIT: actually right now, it's says "FormatException was unhandled" - Input string form was not in correct format.

Comment: Then most likely you have some incorrectly formatted lines in your CSV file. Updated the answer with such check.

Comment: "FormatException was unhandled" is because of incorrect numeric values. Use `int.TryParse()` to check that. Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you have some empty lines in the CSV file.
I suggest using *Linq* to sum up the euros:

```
var data = File
  .ReadLines("C:\\Users\\Andrius\\Desktop\\Mokslams\\C#\\Pratybos\\P2\\P2.1\\turistai.csv")
  .Select(line => line.Split(','))
  .Where(items => items.Length >= 2) // filter out empty/incomplete lines
  // To debug, let's take euros only
  .Select(items => int.Parse(items[1]));
  // In the final solution we'll create Touristai instances
  // .Select(items => new Touristai(items[0], int.Parse(items[1]), int.Parse(items[2])))
  .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, data));

Console.WriteLine(data.Sum());
```

Final solution will be

```
public static void ReadData(out Turistai[] tourists, out int amount) {
  tourists = File
    .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Andrius\Desktop\Mokslams\C#\Pratybos\P2\P2.1\turistai.csv")
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .Where(items => items.Length >= 2) // filter out empty/incomplete lines
    .Select(items => new Touristai(items[0], int.Parse(items[1]), int.Parse(items[2])))
    .ToArray();

  //TODO: check syntax (I've sugested Touristai should have Euro property) 
  amount = tourists.Sum(tourist => tourist.Euro); 
}
```